# Xamarin Forms CollectionView : how to get last item added event

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have a collectionview with infinite scroll.

scroll position jumps to the top of previous set or last or middle of the current set when new set items added to the collection view.

I want to keep the scroll position as the end of the previous set or the first of the current set.

Comment: use an ObservableCollection and monitor the CollectionChanged event

Comment: Hi  Jason, I'm new to xamarin forms could you please provide me a sample code.

Comment: ObservableCollection is a C# class and is not specific to XF.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0